# R: This recursive function outputs an empty list, even though there should be values

Tags: r

I'm creating a function for intersecting a list of vectors.
The idea is for the function to reccur until it intersects the last two vectors in the the list and then move upward.
The problem is that this results in `list()`, even though there should definitely be an answer.

```
intersect_list <- function (x) {
  if (length (x) == 1) {return (unique (x))}
  else {intersect (x [[1]], intersect_list (x [-1]))
  }
}

> listing
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
 [1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6

[[3]]
[1] 2 4

> intersect_list(listing)
list()
```

If I do everything manually, it works fine (naturally) and the output shuld be `[1] 2 4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the case when length(x)==1 to return a vector instead of a list.

```
intersect_list <- function (x) {
  if (length (x) == 1) {return (unique (x[[1]]))}
  else {intersect (x [[1]], intersect_list (x [-1]))
  }
}
```

When `unique` is used on a lists it returns a list with all the unique elements.  It doesn't recursively apply unique on each element. Since in the case when the input length is 1 we still have a list whose first element is a vector it ends up that unique will just return the input.

```
> unique(list(c(1,1,1,2)))
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 2
```

To see how unique is acting take a look at this example

```
> mylist <- list(1:2, 1:2, 3:4, c(1,1,1,2))
> unique(mylist)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 1 1 1 2
```

The first two elements of mylist are the same vector so unique only returns a single instance of it.

So the issue with your function is that you were passing a list into unique which ends up returning a list.  When `intersect` comes across a vector and a list it doesn't do what you were expecting it to.

```
> intersect(1:3, list(1:3))
list()

> intersect(1:3, list(1))
[[1]]
[1] 1

> intersect(list(1:3), list(1:3))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

> intersect(list(1:3, 2:3), list(1:3))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

By changing the `unique(x)` to `unique(x[[1]])` we pass in the vector instead of the list which in turn takes the unique elements from that vector and returns a vector. Then both of the inputs to intersect will be a vector like you expected instead of having a list in there.